# How to link a single row from a table to a whole separate table

Tags: sql, database-design, normalization

I have two tables that I want to link, I want to link every individual `StudentID` in the table with my whole `Questions` table.

I am trying to create something that lets me set any number of questions from the `Question` table to an individual `Student` using the `StudentID` so when a student signs into their account they can view the questions that have been set to them. I think I might need to add a `Boolean` to my questions table called [`set`] or something like that which I can update to true which then means that student can now view that question.

I shall provide my tables to maybe help explain it a bit more:

Questions table(I think I want to link the `StudentID` from this table to the questions):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Questions] (
[QuestionID]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Actual answer]  NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Question Space] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Question Type]  INT           NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QuestionID] ASC)
);
```

Classes table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Classes] (
[ClassSize] INT NULL,
[TeacherID] INT NOT NULL,
[StudentID] INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Classes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TeacherID] ASC, [StudentID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Classes_StudentDetails] FOREIGN KEY ([StudentID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[StudentDetails] ([StudentID]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Classes_TeacherDetails] FOREIGN KEY ([TeacherID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TeacherDetails] ([TeacherID])
);
```

StudentDetails table

(I don't really think it that necessary for me to provide this table but I will anyway):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StudentDetails] (
[StudentID]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Title]         NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Username]      NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Password]      NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[First Name]    NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Last Name]     NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Email Address] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StudentID] ASC)
);
```

Comment: You copied the wrong SQL for your classes table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have M-M relation between `Question` and `Student` i.e. a Question can be set to multiple students and a student can have multiple questions, what you need is an intermediary table which denotes which question is set to which student. Something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QuestionStudentAssociation] (
[QuestionStudentAssociationID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[QuestionID] INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Questions(QuestionID),
[StudentID] INT NOT NULL REFERENCES StudentDetails(StudentID),
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QuestionStudentAssociationID] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Ooo okay thank you, so how would this table work with the data? Would I just have a lot of repeats e.g. a lot of rows with studentID 1 and QuestionID 1,3,4,5,6 if they are set to that student?

Comment: You could add to that table the students answer and perhaps score... These are attributes of the students instance of the question

Comment: @mot375 - Yes, it would have repeats like you mentioned

Comment: @Captain - Yes that's a nice suggestion. if each question can be answered only once by a student, we can add student responses  to this table as well.

Comment: Okay thank you! How would I use that table to then set the questions to the different studentID?

Comment: it would be something like this, Row 1 - StudentID 1, QuestionID 1 , StudentsAnswer "Hubble Telescope" Row 2 - StudentID 2, QuestionID 1,StudentsAnswer NULL -- if the question is just assigned to the student and he has not responded yet. the correct answer of the question will still be in the questions table

Comment: Also what does REFERENCES mean in the table you provided? Is that a foreign key thing?

Comment: I mean what would my SQL query look like? Would it be like: (SELECT Questions ([Question Space]) WHERE QuestionStudentAssociation ([QuestionID] = ..... AND [StudentID] = .....)?

Comment: you would do a `join` between `Question` and `QuestionStudentAssociation` on `QuestionID` with a filter `WHERE  QuestionStudentAssociation.StudentID = ??`

Comment: Oh lord this stuff looks way out of my depth is there anywhere I can read up on this kind of stuff to try and learn how it works?